# Selenium WebDriver is not selecting options from checkbox in HTML. Python

Tags: python

I'm developing something similar to a webscrapping to take informations from a website in html, but I'm having problems to select the options from the checkbox in the internet web page with selenium webdriver. (I'm using Python 3)

Check out part of the code:

```py
driver.get('website_acessed')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="id_presented"]').click()

#this method is presenting this error:
---> 15 driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="id_presented"]')).click()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're showing does not match your code.

`By.XPATH` is indeed a string (`By.XPATH='xpath'`). So it seems that you're calling `driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="id_presented"]'))` in your code and `By.XPATH('//*[@id="id_presented"]')` is raising the error.

However, `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="id_presented"]')` is indeed the right way to find your element.

Comment: I Couldn't get what exactly you mean, but I picked up that, probably, you're talking about using the "ID" in the place of "Xpath". In that case, I've just replaced the ID in place of xpath 'cause that appears in the xpath part of code normally.

Comment: I'm saying that you're using `By.XPATH('//*[@id="id_presented"]')` which is not valid because `By.XPATH` is a `str`, not a function (That's why you're getting `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`).
`find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="id_presented"]')` is the way to go here.

Comment: You're welcome, hope your problem is solved !